# Dynamically set a checkbox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Im trying to dynamically check a checkbox using JQuery 1.5, based on something the user selects from a dropdown list. When the list changes it returns to this function:

```
function displaySystemResults(html){
    var v = html.split(",");
    document.getElementById('fUpdateSystemName').value = v[0];
        if (v[1] == "true"){
            alert("true");
            $('#fUpdateActiveFlag').setAttribute('checked','checked');
        }
    }
```

Here is the dropdown list:

```
<td valign="top"><form:checkbox path="fUpdateActiveFlag"
name='fUpdateActiveFlag' value="checked" />&nbsp;</td>
```

I can't get the checkbox to put a tick in the box. Can anyone spot what im doing wrong? I know its hitting the setAttribute method as the alert box is displaying when it should be set to true.

Comment: `setAttribute()` is a method exposed by DOM elements, not jQuery objects. You're probably looking for `attr("checked", "checked")` or `prop("checked", true)` or `$("#fUpdateActiveFlag")[0].setAttribute("checked", "checked")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#fUpdateActiveFlag')` is the ID selector.

add it to your checkbox

```
<td valign="top"><form:checkbox ID="fUpdateActiveFlag" path="fUpdateActiveFlag"
name='fUpdateActiveFlag' value="checked" />&nbsp;</td>
```

Also, jQuery function is incorrect. `setAttribute` is the JavaScript function, while it looks like you're using jQuery selector, hence the object you select is jQuery object, which does not have a method called `setAttribute`, instead, use `.attr()`:

```
$('#fUpdateActiveFlag').attr('checked','checked')
```

see working example http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/8xp9g/

**Edit**: as per @Dementic 's comment below, you can keep using the `name` attribute, but then you'll have to change your selector to:

```
$('[name="fUpdateActiveFlag"]').attr('checked','checked');
```

see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ruslans/A4D8f/

Comment: or, if you do not want to change the markup `$('[name="fUpdateActiveFlag"]').attr('checked', true);`

Comment: name attribute isn't unique, so I reckon it's best to set an ID here.

Comment: @Tsar and Dementic - thank you both for your responses. Tsar, I couldnt get my code working with your suggestion but Dementic, your code works perfectly so thanks for that! I will accept this as the answer

Comment: use `prop()` over `attr()` in newer versions of jquery

Comment: @Johan - not exactly, have a good read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr